# Why Oracle BULK DML operations are faster

Tags: oracle

Why is an Oracle bulk operation (insert, update, delete) considered faster than a row by row operation? Unless I tell explicitly which partition to insert,modify,delete, a bulk operation would still need to be done in a row by row fashion. Is this assumtion not right? Because the new rows to be inserted may need to go to different data blocks, so how is a BULK going to work?

Comment: "Unless I tell explicitly which partition to insert,modify,delete, a bulk operation would still need to be done in a row by row fashion." Why do you think that?

Comment: Because a bulk update may consist of 1000 rows and they may be scattered all over the place....so how oracle will do the operation in one shot?

Comment: What do you mean by "bulk DML operations"?  Are you talking about set-based operations in SQL?  Or PL/SQL operations using collections?

Comment: @Victor This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453215/oracle-bulk-collect-performance

Comment: @Justin...using BULK COLLECT