# FORALL vs FOR bulk update

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql

This is asked in an interview. The question is, which one is faster, FORALL on 5000 or using FOR on 500 records?
Well, I think that indeed FORALL is faster as far as processing speed is concerned but still it depends on number of rows to be processed, like in the case of above question.
Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Can you please tag the language/database/whatever this question involves? If this is an Oracle PL/SQL question, the answer is covered in quite some detail in the [tuning guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#i48876).

Comment: its for Oracle PL/Sql..

Comment: the detail is fine but what in particular would you answer for that question. is it 5000 with FORALL or 500 with FOR..?

Comment: Since this is an interview question, I'm pretty sure you where not expected to give an exact number (which will probably vary heavily depending on other parameters), but rather come up with technical reasons to show your understanding of the concepts.

Comment: I agree with @dhke.  The only valid answer is "it depends".  If the interviewer is smart they'll want you to explain all the factors which might affect the performance of the two approaches.  Of course they might not be smart, and want a definitive answer.  In which case, why would you want to work there?

Comment: Sometimes you have no choice. `FORALL` is **one single** statement using an internal collection. Inside a `FOR` loop you may have several statements.

Answer (score 15):

It depends.

First, how is the test set up?  In normal code, your `for` loop runs a query and does something so if you're measuring the performance of the loop, you're combining the time required to run the query, fetch the results, and do something with the results.

```
for x in (<<some select statement>>)
loop
  <<do something with x>>
end loop;
```

A `forall` on the other hand, implies that you've already done the work of fetching the data you need to process into a local collection.

```
forall i in 1..l_collection.count
  <<do something>>
```

A performance comparison that includes the time required to run the query and fetch the results in one case and excludes that time from the other case is not a fair comparison.  You'd either need to include the cost of populating the collection in the `forall` case or you would need the `for` loop to iterate over an already populated collection for the comparison to be a fair one.  Which approach you use may have a dramatic affect on the result.

A `forall` eliminates context shifts between the SQL and PL/SQL engines, that's it.  That can be very useful if a substantial fraction of the program's runtime is spent on context shifts.  The more expensive the thing you're doing with the data is (and the more expensive fetching the data is if you're including that time), the smaller the fraction of time spent on context shifts must be.  If you're excluding the time required to fetch the data and the guts of your loop is a trivial operation, the `for` loop solution may well be spending more than 90% of its time doing context shifts so the `forall` solution may be 10 times faster.  If you're including the time required to fetch the data, that time is a large fraction of the overall runtime, and the guts of your loop is an expensive operation, the `for` loop solution is probably spending a small fraction of its time doing context shifts so going to a `forall` won't get you nearly a 10x improvement.

Things get even more complicated if you are including the time required to populate the collection since there are many ways to potentially write that that will have different performance characteristics depending upon whether you're using implicit or explicit cursors and the Oracle version.  That's something that is discussed in more detail in [this question on the performance of a `bulk collect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453215/oracle-bulk-collect-performance/11454950#11454950).

Comment: Congratulations, you've got the job!

Comment: thanks for such a clear explaination.. @David Cave :)